# How to get current date in ddth/mm/yyyy format using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

How can I get the current date in JQuery as a variable and then append to a heading in with an id of `currentdate`, with the format `24th July 2016`?

Answer (score 0):

In [XClass](https://github.com/abdennour/xclass/blob/master/node_modules/x-date/) library  , just do :

```
new Date().format('ddS mmmm yyyy')
```

- dd : day of month
- S : suffix (st,nd,th,..)
- mmmm: Full name of month
- yyyy : year

---

## [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/do5m33aw/)

```js
var out=document.getElementById('out');
out.innerHTML=new Date().format('ddS mmmm yyyy');
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/abdennour/xclass/master/node_modules/x-date/index.js"></script>
<span id="out"></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use javascript [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object and method of it to getting current date and component of it.

```js
var monthName = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
var date = new Date();
var dateStr = date.getDate() + "th " + monthName[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getFullYear();

$("#currentdate").text(dateStr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="currentdate"></div>
```